# Oracle partition by - select ZERO or ONE when group change

Tags: oracle

I've some rows in this way:

```
ID      DESTINATION
1       A
2       A
3       B
4       B
5       B
6       C
```

I would like to have a query that show me when DESTINATION change, and mark it with 0-1 (switching between this).

Right now, i've used partition by to "partition" the destination, and the result is this:

```
ID      DESTINATION     OVER_PARTITION_BY
1       A               1
2       A               2
3       B               1  << Destination change
4       B               2
5       B               3
6       C               1  << Destination change
```

The result that i need is the follow:

```
ID      DESTINATION     OVER_PARTITION_BY
1       A               1
2       A               1
3       B               0   << Group has changed, i switch from 1 to 0
4       B               0
5       B               0
6       C               1   << Group has changed, i switch from 0 to 1
```

Comment: I believe functions `lag` and `lead` will help

Comment: can you show me an example please.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example -

```
with t as
   (select 1 as id, 'A' as DESTINATION from dual union all
    select 2 as id, 'A' from dual union all
    select 3 as id, 'B' from dual union all
    select 4 as id, 'B' from dual union all
    select 5 as id, 'B' from dual union all
    select 6 as id, 'C' from dual)
select id, DESTINATION,  case when mod(dense_rank() over (order by DESTINATION), 2) = 0 then 0 else 1 end as grp_id
 from t
order by id
```

Output:

```
ID      DESTINATION     OVER_PARTITION_BY
1       A               1
2       A               1
3       B               0  << Destination change
4       B               0
5       B               0
6       C               1  << Destination change
```

And another one solution, if values of DESTINATION can be repeated and not be ordered as ID (not the best solution) -

```
with t as
   (select 1 as id, 'A' as DESTINATION from dual union all
    select 2 as id, 'A' from dual union all
    select 3 as id, 'B' from dual union all
    select 4 as id, 'B' from dual union all
    select 5 as id, 'B' from dual union all
    select 6 as id, 'C' from dual union all
    select 7 as id, 'A' from dual)
select id, destination, case when mod(dense_rank() over (order by gr_max),2) = 0 then 0 else 1 end as grp_id
from
   (select d.*, max(gr) over (partition by DESTINATION order by id) as gr_max
      from
       (select t.*,  case when DESTINATION = lag(DESTINATION) over (order by id) then null else dense_rank() over (order by id) end as gr
          from t) d) v
order by id
```

Output:

```
ID      DESTINATION     OVER_PARTITION_BY
1       A               1
2       A               1
3       B               0  << Destination change
4       B               0
5       B               0
6       C               1  << Destination change
7       A               0  << Destination change
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I need to study better partition by functions.